# Find a combinatorial proof that $n{n-1 \choose k}$ = $(k+1)$ ${n \choose k+1}$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

This is a bonus question on a take home quiz. My teacher has not introduced us to combinatorial proofs, just the basics of combinatorics. Does anyone know the correct format for such a proof? Help with the problem would be appreciated as well!

Comment: The idea is to find something that both sides of the equality can be seen to count. If you search the site for `combinatorial proof`, you’ll find many examples.

Comment: Worded it improperly, sorry! This is a practice quiz. If we're able to demonstrate a thought process behind combinatorial proofs, we're given extra credit.

Answer (score 5):

Imagine you are to form a chaired committee of $k+1$ members from a pool of $n$ people.  You can either pick the chair first and then the other $k$ members of the committee, or the committee first and then choose one of the $k+1$ members as the chair.

Comment: I wasn't sure what "find a combinatorial proof" meant. Would it be an example like this? If so, it makes perfect sense to me with just about any example from everyday life. I originally thought it meant to prove that equation.

Comment: @d3m0nxdrums To create a combinatorial proof, you define a set and then count it in two different ways to show they are equal. This is an example of this, with the set defined using words rather than symbols.